# Insert animates of a UIDatePicker under UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a UITextField in a UIView, and when I click on it, I would like to present with an animation a UIDatePicker under the UITextField.

The animation is a simple slide down / slide up.

I will start the animation in this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //check if it is the UITextField I don't want the keyboard for
    if (textField != self.dateTextField)
        return TRUE;

    // Here, I'm starting the animation to present the UIDatePicker under self.dateTextField

    //Return false to prevent the keyboard from appearing.
    return FALSE;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Here, I slide up and hide my UIDatePicker with an animation

    return YES;
}
```

My question is: is it easily possible to do this ? What are your suggestion to start well to do this ? To be honest, I'm not really an experts in iOS animation, and I really don't know how to achieve this.

Thank you for your ideas.

Regards,
Lapinou.

Comment: Why not make the date picker the text field's `inputView`? Then the date picker will animate in and out for you automatically instead of the keyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy that is not very iOS 7 style. But yes it is the easy solution. In iOS 7 you should not use `UITextField` for dates, just use a `UILabel` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and then animate the label into de `UIDatePickerView`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, I agree with you. I tested but it's on iPad, and I think it's not really beautiful to see the UIDatePicker instead of keyboard...

Comment: @rckoenes: Ok, I'll change my UITextField with a UILabel ;) thank you for your suggestion ;)